# How do I update a custom property of an IdentityUser through api controller in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net, api, asp.net-core, usermanager

So I'm working on an api controller and I have an update method like this:

```
 [HttpPost("update")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Update([FromBody] UpdateModel model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            var user = _userManager.Users
                .Include(u => u.Address)
                .FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == model.Email);

            if (user == null)
            {
                return BadRequest(new {Message = "User doesn't exist"});
            }

            user.FirstName = model.FirstName;
            user.LastName = model.LastName;
            user.Address = model.Address;

            await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);

            return Ok(new {Message = "User has been updated successfully"});
        }
```

When updating the user through an api call, the user gets updated, except for the address.

This is the address:

```
public class Address : Entity
{
    public string AddressLine { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

And the update model:

```
    public class UpdateModel
    {
        [Required]
        [MinLength(3)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        
        public Address Address { get; set; }
    }
```

I've done proper migrations, and I tried setting a breakpoint on the user variable. The variable indeeds hold an Address before updateAsync is called.

The user's firstName and lastName both get updated in a POST request, but the address remains null.

Does anyone know why this would happen?

Comment: Can you show us some classes? the custom user, Entity and your DbContext.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are set one to one mapping between User & Address. So first of all check the relation mapping & still not work then try to make new variable of Address and after that assign this new variable to user.Address